# Merge Dataframes and apply different math function by column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 3 DataFrames like below.

A =

```
           ops                 lat
0        9,453              13,536
1        8,666              14,768
2        8,377              15,278
3        8,236              15,536
4        8,167              15,668
5        8,099              15,799
6        8,066              15,867
7        8,029              15,936
8        7,997              16,004
9        7,969              16,058
10       7,962              16,073
```

B =

```
           ops                 lat
0        9,865              12,967
1        8,908              14,366
2        8,546              14,976
3        8,368              15,294
4        8,289              15,439
5        8,217              15,571
6        8,171              15,662
7        8,130              15,741
8        8,093              15,809
9        8,072              15,855
10       8,058              15,882
```

C =

```
           ops                 lat
0        9,594              13,332
1        8,718              14,670
2        8,396              15,242
3        8,229              15,553
4        8,137              15,725
5        8,062              15,875
6        8,008              15,982
7        7,963              16,070
8        7,919              16,159
9        7,892              16,218
10       7,874              16,255
```

How do I merge them into a single dataframe where ops column is a sum and lat column will be average of these three dataframes.

pd.concat() - seems to append the dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely many ways, but to keep it on the same line of thinking as you had with pd.concat, the below will work.

First, concat your dataframes together and then we will calculate .sum() and .mean() on our newly created dataframe and construct our final table with those two fields.

Dummy Data and Example Below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['node1','node1','node1','node2','node2','node3'],
        'Value':[1000,20000,40000,30000,589,682],
        'Value2':[303,2084,494,2028,4049,112]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'Name':['node1','node1','node1','node2','node2','node3'],
       'Value':[1000,20000,40000,30000,589,682],
       'Value2':[8,234,75,123,689,1256]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

joined = pd.concat([df1,df2])

final = pd.DataFrame({'Sum_Col': [joined["Value"].sum()],
                      'Mean_Col': [joined["Value2"].mean()]})


display(final)
```